# Abort active download of packages in Ubuntu from terminal?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, deadlock

I was downloading a package using the terminal. I actually wanted to install package 'A'. But, by mistake started installing package 'B'. I wanted to stop downloading 'B' and start downloading 'A'.

---

I wasn't able to do that. I reset my network connection. I could stop downloading the package B. But, the administrator directory was locked and wasn't able to download other packages which made me to restart my system.

What command should I use to abort the active download of packages in ubuntu?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is when using `apt-get`?

Comment: Ya, when using apt-get

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have you tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: Only press `Ctrl+C` when you are downloading. Once it starts installing, it is better to let it finish installing and then uninstall it because cancelling while it is installing can cause broken packages.

Answer (score 4):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> while packages are downloading, that's fine. Just don't interrupt an install. Also, remember to use

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

after you interrupted the package download, so that the downloaded packages don't take up disk space.